# Is it safe to modify the figure part of an amiibo?

Tags: amiibo

For Super smash bros 4, I want to buy a Mii amiibo. I don't like the design of the Mii Fighter, so I want to cut off the top and make my own design. I have a feeling this is not safe and wiil damage the amiibo, so this is why I am asking this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is completely safe to modify your Amiibo, as the information that's stored is inside the base of the figure. (The NFC chip is actually a really thin wafer as seen on this picture):

[image]

Figure
Image Found at this link: https://www.reddit.com/r/amiibo/comments/346ip6/is_it_possible_to_implant_an_amiibo_chip_into_my/cqsm204

From left to right:

- Figure (on top)
- Underside of base
- Cover of base
- NFC Chip (That's the part that's placed between the two)

The only thing to be careful of is using too much heat in modifying the base or near the base, as that heat can transfer and affect the NFC chip. (So if you use a glue gun on the base, give it time to cool between applications!)